# iconv doesn't properly generate ascii

Tags: bash, cygwin

I have the following:

```
$ file DailyFollowUp.csv
DailyFollowUp.csv: Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with very long lines, with CRLF, CR line terminators
$ iconv -c -t ascii DailyFollowUp.csv > output.txt
$ file output.txt
output.txt: data
```

I am expecting the output.txt file to give ASCII text as a result. Any idea why this isn't working?

This is on Cygwin64

Comment: You did not specified what encoding to convert from (`-f`). What is your `locale`?

Comment: locale is en_US.UTF-8

Comment: Then please provide the `-f` to `iconv`.

Comment: I did, and it did work, but I was hoping iconv would detect automatically the input. And if the source would ever change, it would still work.

Comment: Check the `man` page of iconv: if `-f` is not given, it uses the current locale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not specify the input encoding via `-f`, `iconv` uses the current locale as the default. It does not do any auto-detection.

Answer (score 0):

Even I had the same problem. You have to specify the encoding type
http://lifepluslinux.blogspot.in/2014/09/convert-little-endian-utf-16-to-ascii.html